# Integrating Local SMS Provider Phone Number Verification with Firebase Google Login in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Flutter app with Firebase Google Login implemented for user authentication. As part of the app's functionality, I want to allow users to verify their phone numbers by using a local SMS provider's API for phone number verification, because Firebase phone authentication is costly.

The flow I'm considering is as follows:

1. User logs in with Google using Firebase Google Login.
2. After login, the user is prompted to verify their phone number by receiving an OTP via a local SMS provider's API.
3. The user enters the OTP, and the phone number is verified by the local SMS provider.
4. Once the phone number is verified, I would like to associate this phone number with the already signed-up Google user's details in Firebase.

Is it possible to achieve this integration between Firebase Google Login and a local SMS provider for phone number verification? If so, what would be the recommended approach to store and link the verified phone number with the user's existing Google account in Firebase?

Thank you for your insights and guidance!